# Drupal 7 and Drupal 8.2.6 not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drupal-7

I installed Drupal 8.2.6 on my local machine . The initial index.php screen prompted me for all the needed screens like creation of database, creating and setting up user environment etc. successfully. I can login as the administrator successfully. But any link on the Drupal page gives error like `http://server/drupal-8.2.6/admin/structure`

The output is `The requested URL /drupal-8.2.6/admin/structure was not found on this server.`

I checked on the server folder structure and found that the admin and other folders are not created below drupal-8.2.6.

Any clues where I can look please

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `ubuntu 16.04` and `Apache2`
Then you have to allow `/var/www` directory from apache config file

Locate file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Replace

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

With

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And add add a line at the end of the file

```
ServerName {Host}
```

> Note: Replace `Host` with your host address and restart apache2
>   with command `service apache2 restart`

It works for me!

Answer (score 0):

- Are you using apache?
- Did you enable the rewite module? (Sudo a2enmod rewite)
- is your apache reading Drupal's .htaccess file
  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html

> I checked on the server folder structure and found that the admin and other folders are not created below drupal-8.2.6.

Drupal doesn't create folders in your docroot

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I found the answer here https://www.drupal.org/node/2134281

I added these 3 lines 
`<Directory /var/www>
 AllowOverride all
</Directory>`

to the following file

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

and I am able to browse all the links on the first apache page now. Yes I am using apach2

Answer (score 0):

if you use **Drupal 8** and **nginx** you can edit the following file

> /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

and add this lines :

```
location /drupal8/ {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /drupal8/index.php?$args;
}
```